Extracting the inverse kinematic algorithm from moveit
In the moveit package, I saw that changing the position of the end effector, changes the joint states instantaneously while setting the joint states, so there is some inverse kinematics going on over there. I was wondering if there is a way to extract that algorithm and use it as a node directly, such that I feed in the target position of the end effector as an array and at each end effector position, I get the joint states.
I am quite new to the subject so please use the most basic explanation you can use.

Here is some info on the kinematics libraries used by MoveIt.
I suggest you have a look at Orocos_KDL.
